# Ubuntu not starting after booting

Tags: boot, kernel, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

My Ubuntu was working perfectly, but one day the error came and stayed there. I googled everything but I can't solve the problem. It automatically booted in emergency mode and now it's not booting in default mode.

Error after booting:

```
[ 1263437 Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed 1275454 ] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.

Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device /dev/sda5: recovering journal

/dev/sda: clean, 235301/674624 files, 2391359/2688000 blocks 44134603 ] snd pci_acp3x 0000:04:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode: 1 
You are in emergency mode.
 After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode. 
Press Enter for maintenance
```

After entering `journalctl -xb` :

First red line:

```
11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: Expanded resource Reserved due to conflict with PCI Bus 0000:00
```

Second red line:

```
_0 11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed 
10 11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: fbcon: Taking over console 
10 11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 48376K
10 11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A 10 
10 11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
11:05:26 flyingbeast kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT Ai not connected
```

Third red line:

```
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard 
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2 
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3 5 
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4 5
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5 5  
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6 5 
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7 6 
flying beast kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
```